# SQL error in YII ::: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: yii, mysqli

I Wrote a sql code in yii and its giving this error:

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM users where id in ()

I had no idea why this is happening.........
The code is:

```
$t = implode(",", $array12);
echo $t;
$sql2    = 'SELECT * FROM users where id in ('. $t. ')';
// echo $sql2; die;
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql2);
$row5    = $command->queryAll();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($row5);
echo "</pre>";
```

When I echo the sql using echo $sql2 and die() to see the sql, it gives me this:
SELECT * FROM users where id in (44,45)

Now, I used above sql directly in the the as

```
$sql2    = 'SELECT * FROM users where id in (44,45)';
$command = $connection->createCommand($sql2);
$row5    = $command->queryAll();
```

and its work perfectly, I do not know what to do with my sql.

Comment: I tried to ran your code exactly, but I did not get any error and it's working fine. Are you sure you are doing exactly what's written here ?

Answer (score 1):

You got error when $array12 is empty:

SELECT * FROM users where id in () (check whole sql at the end of a error's message)

You have to check to count elements in $array12:

```
if (count($array12)) {
  $t = implode(",", $array12);
  $sql2    = 'SELECT * FROM users where id in ('. $t. ')';
  // echo $sql2; die;
  $command = $connection->createCommand($sql2);
  $row5    = $command->queryAll();
} else {
  $row5    = array();
}
```